# Google Cloud Run permissions to query bigquery

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-run, google-iam, google-cloud-iam

I have a small python app running in google cloud run with docker. The application is triggered by http requests, executes a query in big query and return the result. Unfortunately I get the following permission error:

```
Reason: 403 POST https://bigquery.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/XXXX/jobs: Access Denied: Project XXXX: User does not have bigquery.jobs.create permission in project XXXX.\n\n(job ID: XXXX-XX-XX-XX-XXXX)\n\n
```

I understand I need to give access from cloud run to big query. How do I do it? to which user? how can i find out?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to add BiqQuery permissions via IAM Roles to the service account assigned to Cloud Run.

To allow Cloud Run to create Big Query jobs (bigquery.jobs.create) you need one of the following roles:

- roles/bigquery.user
- roles/bigquery.jobUser

The service account for Cloud Run is displayed in the Google Cloud Console in the Cloud Run section for your service. Most likely this is `Compute Engine default service account`.

To add a BiqQuery role, you can use the Google Cloud Console. Go to IAM, find the service account. Add roles to the service account.

Documentation:

- [BigQuery predefined Cloud IAM roles](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/access-control#bigquery)
- [Service accounts on Cloud Run (fully managed)](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/service-accounts)
- [Granting roles to service accounts](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/granting-roles-to-service-accounts)

Comment: Your answer is actually correct, and should solve the problem. However I found out that my problem was that I was deploying the app on a project and accessing bigquery on a different project. I accepted your answer because it answer my question and solves the problem given my explanation. However, do you know how to allow the scenario I just mentioned? is it a bad practise maybe?

Comment: A service account or user account can have privileges in more than one project. Just add the identity to each project and assign roles.

Answer (score 2):

One of the issues could be that Service Account which your Cloud Run job is using does not have permissions on BigQuery.

You can update the service account permission and add `roles/bigquery.user` role to create a job.
Also, based on your application requirement add relevant roles. You can see details about different BigQuery roles [here.](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/access-control)

A good rule is provide only required permissions to a service account.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

> The application is triggered by http requests, executes a query in big query and return the result.

From the security standpoint the permissions required are identical to those used by the custom website from this [solution](https://github.com/winwiz1/crisp-bigquery). I'm the author. The website is also triggered by http requests, executes a query in BQ and returns the result. And granting the permission to create jobs (via `bigquery.jobUser` role) is not enough.

You can grant the required permissions to the service account in different ways (e.g. a more sweeping permission and a more restricted one), the details are [here](https://github.com/winwiz1/crisp-bigquery#getting-started) at the Step 6.

Generally speaking, the more restricted and the more granular the permissions are the better for security.

I'm adding extra clarifications and also pasting specific instructions related to Google's tools usage.

1. To add the permission to create and run jobs (the BQ error message says this permission is lacking) execute the command:

   ```
   gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding <project-name> --member=serviceAccount:<sa-name>@<project-name>.iam.gserviceaccount.com --role roles/bigquery.jobUser
   ```

   The command can be executed in Cloud Shell, open it using the "Activate Cloud Shell" icon in [BigQuery Web UI](https://console.cloud.google.com/bigquery) or from other Google Console page. Replace the placeholders:

   `<sa-name>` - replace with service account name used by Cloud Run,
   `<project-name>` - replace with the project name.

   The command adds the role `bigquery.jobUser` to the service account. Do not add other permissions/roles to solve the inability to create/run jobs because excessive permissions are bad for security.
2. Another permission is required to read BQ data. There are two options to add it:

   - Grant the `bigquery.dataViewer` role to the service account:

   ```
   gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding <project-name> --member=serviceAccount:<sa-name>@<project-name>.iam.gserviceaccount.com --role roles/bigquery.dataViewer
   ```

   Then proceed to the next step. Not recommended unless you are using a throw-away project. The drawback of this approach is granting permissions to view all project datasets.

   - Take more granular approach (recommended) by allowing the service account to query one dataset only. This is the approach described below.

   Execute the commands replacing `<ds-name>` with the dataset name (used by your query):

   ```
   bq show --format=prettyjson <ds-name>  >/tmp/mydataset.json  
   vi /tmp/mydataset.json
   ```

   Using vi, append the following item to the existing `access` array and replace the placeholders before saving the file:

   ```
   ,
   {  
   "role": "READER",  
   "userByEmail": "[<sa-name>@<project-name>.iam.gserviceaccount.com](mailto:<sa-name>@<project-name>.iam.gserviceaccount.com)"  
   }
   ```

   Execute the command to effect the changes for the dataset:

   ```
   bq update --source /tmp/mydataset.json <ds-name>
   ```